# Yarn install azure pipeline "error an unexpected error occurred : [azure-registry] : Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\""

Tags: javascript, azure-pipelines, yarnpkg

I'm trying to build my Quasar project on an azure pipeline.

My pipeline worked perfectly for a week but yesterday, I don't know why, I can't execute "yarn install" without seeing this error.

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "{my-azure}/npm/registry/@nestjs/elasticsearch/-/elasticsearch-8.0.0.tgz: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\""
```

Each time, it's a different library.

I try to delete my yarn lock but then I have another error when i'm doing yarn install

```
Couldn't find package "{random library}" on te "npm" registry...
```

I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a permissions issue, here are common solutions:

- Check the PAT token in your .npmrc file, it may have expired;
- Check permissions on your feed. Give the contributor permission for the corresponding user, the credentials are in the .npmrc file. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#configure-feed-settings)

I've sometimes faced a similar issue where npm can't find a package. It could be related to the upstream source order in your feed, check out this documentation for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#order-your-upstream-sources-intentionally